# Nginx with Mod Security 3. white list by IP fails

Tags: nginx, mod-security

I have installed Mod Security 3 on my Nginx server.
Up to date and seeing multiple pages on how to put an IP on the white list, I find that all docs talk to me about doing something, and that causes me a configuration error in nginx.

#### whitelist.conf (call on modsecurity.conf after read all rules files)

```
SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "@ipMatch 192.168.110" phase:1,nolog,allow,ctl:ruleEngine=Off
```

Error

```
root@hq:/etc/nginx/modsec/whitelist# nginx -t 
nginx: [emerg] "modsecurity_rules_file" directive Rules error. File: /etc/nginx/modsec/whitelist/whitelist.conf. Line: 1. Column: 19.  in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:4
```

Some body can help me?

### main.conf

```
# From https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/blob/master/
# modsecurity.conf-recommended
#
# Edit to set SecRuleEngine On
Include "/etc/nginx/modsec/modsecurity.conf"

# Basic test rule
# SecRule ARGS:testparam "@contains test" "id:1234,deny,status:403"
# OWASP CRS v3 rules
Include /usr/local/owasp-modsecurity-crs-3.0.2/crs-setup.conf
Include /usr/local/owasp-modsecurity-crs-3.0.2/rules/REQUEST-900-EXCLUSION-RULES-BEFORE-CRS.conf
Include /usr/local/owasp-modsecurity-crs-3.0.2/rules/REQUEST-901-INITIALIZATION.conf
Include /usr/local/owasp-modsecurity-crs-3.0.2/rules/REQUEST-905-COMMON-EXCEPTIONS.conf
Include /usr/local/owasp-modsecurity-crs-3.0.2/rules/REQUEST-910-IP-REPUTATION.conf
Include /usr/local/owasp-modsecurity-crs-3.0.2/rules/REQUEST-911-METHOD-ENFORCEMENT.conf
Include /usr/local/owasp-modsecurity-crs-3.0.2/rules/REQUEST-912-DOS-PROTECTION.conf
Include /usr/local/owasp-modsecurity-crs-3.0.2/rules/REQUEST-913-SCANNER-DETECTION.conf
Include /usr/local/owasp-modsecurity-crs-3.0.2/rules/REQUEST-920-PROTOCOL-ENFORCEMENT.conf
Include /usr/local/owasp-modsecurity-crs-3.0.2/rules/REQUEST-921-PROTOCOL-ATTACK.conf
Include /usr/local/owasp-modsecurity-crs-3.0.2/rules/REQUEST-930-APPLICATION-ATTACK-LFI.conf
Include /usr/local/owasp-modsecurity-crs-3.0.2/rules/REQUEST-931-APPLICATION-ATTACK-RFI.conf
Include /usr/local/owasp-modsecurity-crs-3.0.2/rules/REQUEST-932-APPLICATION-ATTACK-RCE.conf
Include /usr/local/owasp-modsecurity-crs-3.0.2/rules/REQUEST-933-APPLICATION-ATTACK-PHP.conf
Include /usr/local/owasp-modsecurity-crs-3.0.2/rules/REQUEST-941-APPLICATION-ATTACK-XSS.conf
Include /usr/local/owasp-modsecurity-crs-3.0.2/rules/REQUEST-942-APPLICATION-ATTACK-SQLI.conf
Include /usr/local/owasp-modsecurity-crs-3.0.2/rules/REQUEST-943-APPLICATION-ATTACK-SESSION-FIXATION.conf
Include /usr/local/owasp-modsecurity-crs-3.0.2/rules/REQUEST-949-BLOCKING-EVALUATION.conf
Include /usr/local/owasp-modsecurity-crs-3.0.2/rules/RESPONSE-950-DATA-LEAKAGES.conf
Include /usr/local/owasp-modsecurity-crs-3.0.2/rules/RESPONSE-951-DATA-LEAKAGES-SQL.conf
Include /usr/local/owasp-modsecurity-crs-3.0.2/rules/RESPONSE-952-DATA-LEAKAGES-JAVA.conf
Include /usr/local/owasp-modsecurity-crs-3.0.2/rules/RESPONSE-953-DATA-LEAKAGES-PHP.conf
Include /usr/local/owasp-modsecurity-crs-3.0.2/rules/RESPONSE-954-DATA-LEAKAGES-IIS.conf
Include /usr/local/owasp-modsecurity-crs-3.0.2/rules/RESPONSE-959-BLOCKING-EVALUATION.conf
Include /usr/local/owasp-modsecurity-crs-3.0.2/rules/RESPONSE-980-CORRELATION.conf
Include /usr/local/owasp-modsecurity-crs-3.0.2/rules/RESPONSE-999-EXCLUSION-RULES-AFTER-CRS.conf

# Mias
Include /usr/local/owasp-modsecurity-crs-3.0.2/rules/REQUEST-903.9002-WORDPRESS-EXCLUSION-RULES.conf

# Whitelisting
Include /etc/nginx/modsec/whitelist/*.conf
```

Comment: Please share your ```default.conf``` file too.

Answer (score 0):

Within CRS 3.x two files are provided to help you add these different rule modifications, they are: rules/REQUEST-00-LOCAL-WHITELIST.conf.example and rules/RESPONSE-99-EXCEPTIONS.conf.example. As is noted in the Installing OWASP CRS documentation, the .example extension is provided specifically so that when these files are renamed, future updates will not overwrite these files. As is listed within the Installing OWASP CRS documentation, before adding a whitelist or exception modification you should rename these files to end in the .conf exception.

https://www.modsecurity.org/CRS/Documentation/exceptions.html